# Can I use the phrase_prefix query type with the fuzziness option?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using the `fuzziness` option and I want to add a "prefix functionality" to find documents where one of the fields contains a term that starts with X.

I have a `multi_match` query and to my understanding you can't use type `phrase_prefix` with `fuzziness`. Is there another way I can do it?

Here's my query:

`"query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "query": this.queryTerm,
        "operator": "and",
        "fields": ["title", "content", "author.name", "tags"],
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
}`